# Overlap a layout with viewPager

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-viewpager

maybe you can help me. I want to use viewPager to overlap an other layout. so for example: I the first Fragment. On this Fragment is a picture, than I swipe to the right and then the second Fragment should just go over the first Fragment. It's like in the Android Youtube App in which you swipe from left to right and the settings and etc go over the main layout(like in the picture). Can you tell me what i have to do?
Thanks a lot, Vinzenz.

picture:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQ8gL.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for is actually not related to `ViewPager`.  There is another layout you can use to implement the same navigation pane overlay: `DrawerLayout` link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html